# In GCP share a VPN gateway with other projects

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpn

I'm in the process of starting the design of the networks (VPC, subnetworks and such) as part of the process of moving a rather complex organization on-premise structure, on the cloud.

The chosen provider is GCP and I read and taken the courses to be associate engineer. However, the courses I've followed don't go into details of the technical aspects of doing something like this, just present you with the possible options.

My background is of a senior backend, then fullstack, developer. So I lack some of the very interesting and useful knowledge of a sysadmin unfortunately.

Our case is as follows:

- On premise VMs on several racks, reachable only inside a VPN
- Several projects on the GCP Cloud
- Two of them need to connect to the on-premise VPN but there could be more
- Some projects see each other resources (VMs, SQL, etc) using VPC Peering
- Gradually we will abandon the on-premise, unless we find some legacy application that really is messed up

Now, I could just create a new VPN connection for every project from `Hybrid Connectivity -> VPN` but I'd rather create a project dedicated to having the VPN gateway set up and allow other projects to use that resources.

Is this a possible configuration? Is it a valid design? As far as I explored the VPN creation, it seems that I'll have to create a VM that will expose an IP acting as gateway, if that's the case I was thinking to be using the VPC peering to allow other projects to exit into the on premise VPN. No idea if I'm talking gibberish here. I'm still waiting for some information (IKE shared key, etc) before attempting anything, so I'm rather lost at this point.

Comment: The first detail missing from your question is which VPN are you using on both ends? What routing protocol (static or BGP)? Client->Site or Site->Site? What is the required bandwidth? Unfortunately, VPNs and VPCs require numerous details and skills to set up correctly. I recommend studying various Google How-to-Guides and other articles on VPNs in Google Cloud. Take a look at deploying OpenVPN to get your feet wet with the issues of setting up a simple VPN (Client->Site), routing/peering between VPCs, etc. OpenVPN is very simple to deploy. There is even a Google Marketplace image.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for these suggestions. I've not all the information as the company has an "operation" department that really is doing mostly support to the regular company users (non tech) but is also the dept. that has kept all contacts with an external company that manage our vpn and firewall management. All I know is that we use a Cisco AnyConnect when a client need to connect to the VPN but this is gonna be more like cluster of applications (in GPC) connecting to their backend (on premise). We will gradually move towards full GCP over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take in consideration several aspect:

- Cost: if you set up a VPN in each project, and if you have to [double your connectivity for HA](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/moving-to-ha-vpn), it will be expensive. If you have only 1 gateway project, it's cheaper
- Cheaper, imply trade off. VPN have [limited bandwidth: 3Gbps](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/quotas) (Cloud Interconnect also, but higher and more expensive). If all your projects use the same VPN thanks to mutualization, take care at this bottleneck.

If you want to mutualise, at least for DEV/UAT project, I recommend you to use VPC Peering, I mean 1 VPN project, and others with [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering). Take care at your IP range assign for peering. If you are interested, [I wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-reach-on-premise-resources-with-serverless-products-747ebd37dc8e)

It's also possible to use [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), which is great! But there is less compatibility with several product (for example, serverless VPC Connector for Cloud Function and App Engine isn't yet compliant with shared VPC).

Comment: yeah, I was aware of the higher cost if duplicating the VPN connectivity, that's another reason I was asking for info about this other design. The 3GBS is more than enough as the connection will be used by web application used internally (we are talking less than 100 users per application, some with even just 5-10 total users). I'll check out your article to get more information about this. Thanks you!